# The best practise when to use PHP exception handling

Tags: php, exception

I know this question has been asked before numorous times but they seem to have a desktop application background and not web application. I am currently building a web application using PHP. I'm going to use a controller and model file to demonstrate my question.

Controller file

This file calls upon the database to query and fetch data

```
<?php public function index() {
    $this->database->query("SELECT user_name, FROM test WHERE user_name = :user_name");
    $this->database->execute_query("jim");
    $this->view->data = $this->database->fetch_query();
?>
```

The database file

```
<?php

class DB {

    private $datasourcename;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $connection;
    private $prepare;
    private $query;

    function __construct($dsn, $user, $password) {

        $this->datasourcename = $dsn;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;    

        $this->connection = new PDO($this->datasourcename, $this->user, $this->password);
    }

    public function query($query) {

        $this->query = $query;
        try {
            if (empty($query)) {

                throw new Exception("The query is empty");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "<br/>";
        }
        if (strstr($query, ":") == FALSE) {
            return $this->connection->query($query);
        } else {

            $this->prepare = $this->connection->prepare($query);
        }
    }

    public function execute_query($valarg = array()) {

        try {
            if (empty($valarg)) {

                throw new Exception("There are no values in the execute query function");
                return false;
            }
            if (is_array($valarg) == false) {

                throw new Exception("The values inserted are not in an array");
                return false;
            } else {

                $query = $this->query;
                $paramkeys = array();
                $paramArr = array();

                if (strstr($query, ":")) {    

                    preg_match_all("/:(\w+)/", $query, $paramkeys);

                    $paramArr = array_combine($paramkeys[0], $valarg);

                    $this->prepare->execute($paramArr);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "<br/>";
        }
    }

    public function fetch_query() {

        try {
            if($this->execute_query() == false)    {

                 throw new Exception("Sorry you need to fix this first");
            }

             if($this->query() == false)    {

                 throw new Exception("Sorry you need to fix this first");
            }
            else    {

                 $result = $this->prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                return $result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "<br/>";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I have used exception handling in my database class as a way for a developer to use the functions provided by that class correctly in order for the application to work, am I right im thinking that this is the best practise to use them? Is there a clear cut best practise when and how to use them? I have read similar questions on this site but the background was desktop application design and not web application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Web programming is no different than desktop programming in this regard.

Use exceptions for *exceptional* events.  Use return values for anything expected.

I think seeing an empty query result isn't something that will have an exception thrown, generally.  I'd just return no data.  If the database query failed somehow, that would be a reason to throw an exception.  Also, your exception messages should probably be more descriptive, rather than "you need to fix this".

Finally, in PHP 5.3, you can set an inner exception by passing it as the third parameter in the `Exception` constructor.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php

Comment: An empty query in this context is **absolutely** an exception.  There's no valid reason to ever be trying to query nothingness, which means the calling code is broken in some way.  Not throwing an exception here would do nothing but muddy the waters when trying to track down the source of that bug.

Comment: @drrcknlsn, I was speaking generally.  If the application is expecting and requiring a result to continue, then yes, an exception makes perfect sense.

Comment: Even if it doesn't require a result to continue, an empty query is a sign that something is wrong.  Returning nothing would allow the calling code to continue on unaware of the problem if it wasn't expecting a return value (e.g. it was supposed to have been a command query).

Comment: @drrcknlsn, If I do a query looking through some products table for all products named "x" and no rows are returned, I don't see that as an exception.  It just means that no products were found.  Like I said, it depends on what you are trying to do.  An empty query result does *not* always mean something is wrong.

Comment: Of course that's not an exception, but you're confusing an empty query *result* with an empty *query*.  As you say, the former is not always a problem depending on the query, but the latter is **always** a problem.  There is never a case where an empty *query* is valid, and it is always an indicator that something is broken.

Comment: @drrcknlsn, Oh!  I see where the confusion is.  Yes, I completely agree.  I meant to say query **result** in my post, not empty query.  Fixing that now...